# Single Quotes in Excel Cells

Tags: excel

Why do I have two spreadsheets, and the cells are formatted as Text, but only one spreadsheet seems to automatically add a single quote before each value in the cell?

I have tried stripping out the quote via VBA but it remains.  I understand it likely has zero impact, as when I copy the value out of Excel into another sheet, the single quote is not present.

I can only think it is related to a setting somewhere in Excel in terms of what is displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a `Range.PrefixCharacter` which has different meanings depending on whether or not you have the Lotus transition boxes checked.

To remove it, run VBA code like:

```
dim myRng as range
set myRng = Range("A1:A100") 'or whatever    

    with myRng
        .Formula = .Formula
    end with
```

Comment: I don't have the Lotus options checked and I do get these added.  Here is an example of a document identifier which if I paste in, gets a single quote added automatically.  Doc ID-004201002.  If I try and remove it, it gets added back automatically - nothing I can do to remove it.  Doesnt matter if my cell format is Text or General.

Comment: @smackenzie If I add it manually, the above code removes it. What happens when you run the above code on a cell (or range) that contains the prefix character?

Comment: Doesn't work.  In my change event I am looping through each cell in the "Target" parameter and setting this, and it is still there.  Lotus options are not checked

Comment: @smackenzie Run it over a range from a Regular Module, not a sheet module.  Use a whole range reference as I showed in my last edit.

Comment: actually it does work, I added the code into my double click event not my change event.....

Comment: @smackenzie Sure would be nice to know how it got there in the first place. I suppose you could troubleshoot on the errant worksheet by starting Excel in Safe Mode. Then trying to paste in as you did before.  If the prefix character doesn't appear, then you could do some detective work to figure out which add-in is causing the problem.

Comment: Accepted....it happens in a different blank spreadsheet also, almost as if Excel recognises it as being partly numeric and so forces it to text

Comment: @smackenzie Try it after starting excel in Safe Mode

Comment: Actually doesn't work.  Looping over the Target cells affected in Worksheet_Change and applying this to each cell, doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Doesn't work in Safe Mode; or the solution doesn't work? If the latter, then run the code from a **Regular Module**, over the entire affected range `myRng`, and see if that works.

Comment: The issue seems to kick in when doing a PasteSpecial(xlFormats) onto the cell.  But even after the formatting is applied, if I do .formula = .formula, the single quote remains and cannot even be manually deleted

Comment: Perhaps [Remove Leading Apostorphe](http://eforexcel.com/wp/article-27-remove-leading-apostrophe/) will help.

Answer (score 0):

File - Options - Advanced section, uncheck the 'Transition navigation keys' option at the bottom.

Comment: Will try, seems a strange option?!

Comment: It wouldn't if you were a Lotus 123 user. ;)

Comment: What does a single quote denominating a text entry have to do with Lotus navigation??  This option was not set anyway

Comment: It doesn't actually indicate *text* - it's a left alignment indicator.

Comment: How did that get in there without any of these Lotus options selected.  All over the web it states this forces the cell to be treated as text.  I use it when I want to prevent 16 digit identifiers to get converted to scientific notations.